# We release the app on play store, but i need to test, how to downgrade the app?

Tags: google-play, release-management

I have an app which was running V1.1 and our team made some changes to the application. We release V1.2 which need some config file.

But currently, we don't have any phone installed V1.1. Even we have the apk for V1.1 but when we install this apk, Google play store says the app is already installed (uninstalled, open).

**I need to get the point where play-store says ' update & open '.**

How can we test the 'update' step, nowhere in the phone, V1.1 installed from play store?
we release V1.2 on play store.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the v1.1 APK, you can install it on your phone through ADB. Make sure you uninstall the store version. You can never downgrade an application.

Of course, the APK should have been signed by the same keystore.

After installing the V1.1 through ADB, you can go to the Play store, and it should prompt you to upgrade to V1.2.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, but sorry to say that, it didn't work. This process is also showing the same result as all steps (uninstall & OPEN).

Comment: Uninstall and OPEN? Can you share the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is insisting on uninstall first, rather than updating will probably be because the version you are adb installing is signed with a different key (certificate). This is probably because you use Google Play App Signing. You need to install with adb a version of the 1.1 APK that was signed by Google.

If you:
  - go to your Play Console
  - choose your app
  - go to App Releases
  - find the release with 1.1 in it
  - download the APK

I think you get a version of the old APK signed by Google Play, which should then update rather than needing an uninstall.